# Alternative to a html combo box for mobile apps using phonegap

Tags: mobile, dojo, cordova

I am trying to write a mobile version of our site.  It is a simple form with several fields, a few which are combo boxes.  I am using dojo and phonegap to try and make an interface that will work on all mobile devices.

I am running into a design issue with combo boxes.  How should they be handled on mobile devies?  I wrote some js that sends the user to another screen that displays a list and on selection of a list item it is populated in the form textbox.  This seems like a hack and only works on the emulator not my android device. Doesn't work on the device because the keypad pops up since it is a text field.

I saw that in dojo 1.7 a combo box will be available.  I can't really wait for this.  I just figured there are other more elegant solutions already out there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: 1.7 [is out](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/), by the way.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Do you know how I can build the mobile compenents into one file?  I did with 1.6.1 using http://build.dojotoolkit.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the solution for this type of problem with touch interfaces is to use "picker tools", You are probably familiar with those on native ios or android devices. I know that both Sencha Touch and Jquery frameworks allow you to implement these into regular websites. Using either of these would require you to add the appropriate files to your project.

To see a sencha touch example go [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/)  and click "user interface" and then click forms. You will then see a form with some of the entries having a drop down icon. Clicking them will pull up a "picker". You can click up on the top right for the source code.
Jquery can do the same thing, but i've no experience with it. Good luck. (both are free solutions).

Comment: link is outdated? could not find "user interface" pleas include a screenshot here

Answer (score 0):

The mobile Dojox version offers a combobox that is built in, I'm not 100% sure this is what you are looking for though.

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/mobile/ComboBox

Comment: link is dead. please include screenshot or code here.